# Mongodb query find with array with interchangin values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to figure out if I can query a document with a column with an array.

but if possible if the values are interchanging. is it possible to search array

with out correctly sorting the values? because I will use this parameter later

on an update upsert.

it works if I do:

```
players:[ "1","2"]
```

but if I do this it returns zero:

```
players:["2","1"]
```

Document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58218b1709896dabcef00cff"),
    "players" : [ 
        "1", 
        "2"
    ],
    "total_games" : 1,
    "stats" : [ 
        {
            "player_id" : "1",
            "wins" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "player_id" : "2",
            "wins" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Query (returns 1):

```
db.getCollection('head_to_head_stats').find({players:[ "1","2"]})
```

Query (returns 0):

```
db.getCollection('head_to_head_stats').find({players:[ "2","1"]})
```

Comment: $in would fetch the results with 1 or 2 on it though. if its [2,3] or [2,4] would still show.

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/).

> The [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator selects the documents where the value of a
>   field is an array that contains all the specified elements.

```
db.getCollection('head_to_head_stats').find({players: {$all:[ "2","1"]}})
```

Comment: Worked like how I wanted. I am wondering how I would use this on an upsert. but might just do find and insert/update.

Comment: You can post other question for that :)